# World in Conflict--are there still servers out there?

Tags: world-in-conflict-soviet-assault

I recently played World in Conflict at a friend's house (single player), and I liked it a lot. It's not very expensive (complete edition is 19.99 now), but I don't want to buy it if there's nobody to play with online.

Are there still servers out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are still servers out there with players on them.
Right now about 15 servers that are full and countless others which are empty.

The game is really fun when playing (especially multiplayer). I would say a definite buy :)

Screenshot from same day:
[image]

Comment: I bought this game when it first game out and loved it.  I was thinking about digging it out of the closet, but are there still servers going in 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Just to prove that there are servers and more importantly people out there playing, [this](http://www.massgate.net/profile.php?0,563478) player profile (which I chose at random) played an online match earlier today.  Granted he's the number one player, but he is playing and there are people who are interested in that fact :-p

Hope that helps.